# Why do i get a repeated QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a Qt application that deals with scheduling employees. The header data for the main QTableView is a pointer to a QStringList. The headerData() function works correctly, but when i add a string to the list elsewhere, it appends the entire list including the new string to the end of the list.

For example, if i have the list 1,2,3 and i append 4 to it, then iterating through the list based on the pointer gives the result 1,2,3,1,2,3,4. I don't know a better way than using pointers to have multiple classes access the same data. Does anyone know how to fix the repeating list?

Example Code

```
//function to save a new employee in memory
bool EmployeeViewDialog::saveEmployee(Employee *e)
    {

employees->insert(e->name,e);
*employeeNames << e->name;
for (int i = 0; i < employeeNames->length(); i++) {
        qDebug() << employeeNames->at(i);
    }

    QList<QStandardItem*> items;
    items << new QStandardItem(e->name);
    items << new QStandardItem(e->id);
    items << new QStandardItem(e->phone);
    items << new QStandardItem(e->email);
    model->appendRow(items);
    return true;
}
```

The append was just changed to the << method. It is the employeeNames << e->name; line.
The for loop iterates through the list and does the same thing as what happens in the external class.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to append to the QStringList?

Comment: Its just a simple `list->append(someString);` that i'm using to append to the list. Then iterating through it in another class gives the doubled list.

Comment: This is difficult to assess, you should try to provide a minimal example where this occurs. I suspect the problem is not in the line you think.

Comment: @pippin1289 edited my original post.

Comment: I don't think the problem is here, because items will contain 4 items at the end of the function. Show the code that show you the list is repeated.

Comment: It's there. The for loop in the code shows the repeated list. It is created from a QMap<QString,Employee*>.keys() function, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you always adding the whole list to your model?

Comment: Is written to the list from other locations? How's saveEmployees() called? I'd step through with a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Found the issue, thanks for the help. It turned out that i added code to save new employees to the list, then when i built the model the first time, i called that method, which added all of the employees again.